# Custom navigation bar xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm trying to create this custom navigation bar,but I can't find anywhere if this is even possible.
here. I wonder if is possible to add this custom size bar.I know how to add the green/blue one, what I need is to add this custom size image in purple.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this issue. You can draw a testing image like following picture(Note:My picture have a blank view in the top, I do not have tools(such as) to fix that).

[image]

Then I used `AbsoluteLayout` to make a custom navigation bar with following code.(Note:There is a blank space at the top of my picture, so I have to adjust the placement, you can adjust it with your layout)

```
 <AbsoluteLayout  >
        
            <Image Source="my.png"   BackgroundColor="Transparent"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,-0.025,1,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional"
              />

        <Label Text="Hi,Luisa" TextColor="Black" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.01,50,20" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />

        <Label Text="Credit:Rs 255.00" TextColor="Black" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95,0.01,150,20" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
    
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Or you can use Skiasharp to draw it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/circle

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget the accept this answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner), it will help others who have similar issue.